# Method returning max Value not working

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong here. Anyone care to explain? It compiles and runs but I keep getting an error at line 50 which is the return line.

Also if I change the code below to "int max = (number1, number2) " i get the can not find symbol error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

> ```
> int max = max(num1, num2);
> ```

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodLab {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     // variable declarations for part 1
     String title;
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     // prompt for input for part 1
     System.out.print("Enter a title:");
     title = in.next();
     System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
     firstName = in.next();     
     System.out.print("Enter a your last name:");
     lastName = in.next();
     // call the method for part 1
     greeting(title, firstName, lastName);

     // variable declarations for part 2
     int number1;
     int number2;
     // user prompts for part 2
     System.out.print("Enter first number:");
     number1 = in.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Enter second number:");
     number2 = in.nextInt();
     // call the method for part 2 inside the println statement
     System.out.println("The largest number is " + max(number1, number2));
 }

 /******************** greeting method goes here*********************/
   public static void greeting(String proper, String fname, String lname){
     System.out.println();
     System.out.printf("Dear " + proper +" "+ fname + " "+ lname);
     System.out.println();
   }






  /***********************end of method*************************/

  /******************** max method goes here*********************/
   public static int max(int num1,int num2){
     int max = max(num1, num2);
     return max;
   }
```

Comment: `int max = max(num1, num2);` do you want to call the same method here or some other method.

Comment: Thank you for making me realize what I was actually calling. Sometimes I get so caught up I go over and over missing obvious things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int max = Math.max(num1, num2)` this will return the max number.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int max(int num1,int num2){
     int max = max(num1, num2);
     return max;
   }
```

This method would never complete. This is going to call max again and again until you run out of stack space. And when you do, it throws a stack overflow error. You should change it to

```
public static int max(int num1,int num2){
     int max = num1>num2?num1:numb2; // return the highest number.
     return max;
   }
```

EDIT: Since you mentioned that you are new to programming, let me add few more detail. If you are in a method A and you call a method B, some amount of space in the stack segment is reserved so that the control knows the line location in method A to resume execution after completing method B. In your case, the max method calls max method again and again. This directly means that more and more space in stack segment gets reserved for each method call. And at some point, it runs out of available space in stack memory and you would end up with such StackOverflow problem.

In general, any method calling itself without modifying the inputs is a red flag in most scenario. This is the case with your max method.

Comment: Thank you! Your details really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

In your max(int num1, int num2) there is no logic, it's just calling itself so will never end:

use like below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodLab {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     // variable declarations for part 1
     String title;
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     // prompt for input for part 1
     System.out.print("Enter a title:");
     title = in.next();
     System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
     firstName = in.next();     
     System.out.print("Enter a your last name:");
     lastName = in.next();
     // call the method for part 1
     greeting(title, firstName, lastName);

     // variable declarations for part 2
     int number1;
     int number2;
     // user prompts for part 2
     System.out.print("Enter first number:");
     number1 = in.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Enter second number:");
     number2 = in.nextInt();
     // call the method for part 2 inside the println statement
     System.out.println("The largest number is " + max(number1, number2));
 }

 /******************** greeting method goes here*********************/
   public static void greeting(String proper, String fname, String lname){
     System.out.println();
     System.out.printf("Dear " + proper +" "+ fname + " "+ lname);
     System.out.println();
   }






  /***********************end of method*************************/

  /******************** max method goes here*********************/
   public static int max(int num1,int num2){
     return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
   }
```